# Why am I getting full zero predictions by using DeepLab v3+ in WiSe dataset, even though the loss keeps decreasing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, deeplab, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to train the DeepLab v3+ model (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/research/deeplab/) on the WiSe dataset ([https://cvhci.anthropomatik.kit.edu/~mhaurile/wise/](https://cvhci.anthropomatik.kit.edu/%7Emhaurile/wise/)). I have modified the parameters in the scripts provided and started running the `train.py` script, but even though the loss keeps decreasing (from about 2.7 at step 10 to about 1.9 at step 100), I am getting all-zeros in the predictions made by the exported checkpoints. Even on every train image, I am getting an all-zero prediction. 
Dataset information (I have processed the dataset to suit my needs): 
Train images: 1222 
Val images: 100 
Total images: 1322 
Total classes: 9 (including background) 
Classes: ['background', 'TitleSlide', 'PresTitle', 'ImageCaption', 'Image', 'Code', 'Enumeration', 'Tables', 'Paragraph'] \

I added the following code to `datasets/data_generator.py`:

```
_WISE_SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 1222,
        'trainval': 1322,
        'val': 100,
    },
    num_classes=10,        # 8 foreground + 1 background + 1 ignore
    ignore_label=255,
)

_DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
    'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
    'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
    'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
    'wise_seg': _WISE_SEG_INFORMATION,
}
```

Note that in my dataset, no image actually has any pixel with label 255. Each label is in the range [0, 8]. I have also tried setting `num_classes` to 9, without any success.
My directory structure is as follows:

```
deeplab
├── datasets
│   ├── wise_seg
│   │   ├── exp
│   │   │   └── train_on_train_set
│   │   │       ├── eval
│   │   │       ├── export
│   │   │       ├── train
│   │   │       └── vis
│   │   ├── init_models
│   │   │   └── xception
|   |   |       ├── model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
|   |   |       └── model.ckpt.index
│   │   ├── tfrecord
│   │   └── WiSe
│   │       ├── Annotations
│   │       ├── ImageSets
│   │       │   └── Segmentation
|   |       |       ├── train.txt
|   |       |       ├── trainval.txt
|   |       |       └── val.txt
│   │       ├── JPEGImages
│   │       ├── SegmentationClass
│   │       └── SegmentationClassRaw
│   └── __pycache__
|------ Other stuff
```

The command which I used to run the training:

```
python ./train.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --train_split="train" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --train_crop_size="513,513" \
  --train_batch_size=16 \
  --training_number_of_steps=30000 \
  --fine_tune_batch_norm=true \
  --tf_initial_checkpoint="./datasets/wise_seg/init_models/xception/model.ckpt" \
  --train_logdir="./datasets/wise_seg/train" \
  --dataset="wise_seg" \
  --initialize_last_layer=false \
  --last_layers_contain_logits_only=false \
  --dataset_dir="./datasets/wise_seg/tfrecord"
```

Note that I have set `initialize_last_layer = False` and `last_layers_contain_logits_only = False`. I have used the ImageNet pretrained Xception-65 model as the backbone network, which I downloaded from the link given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md) (specifically, I used `xception_65_imagenet`). 
I also made the following change in `utils/train_utils.py`:

```
exclude_list = ['global_step', 'logits']
  if not initialize_last_layer:
    exclude_list.extend(last_layers)
```

When I execute the training, it is successfully able to get to the training part, and it has been trained up to about step 110 now. I exported an intermediate checkpoint using the following command:

```
python ./export_model.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --checkpoint_path="./datasets/wise_seg/exp/train_on_train_set/train/model.ckpt-41" \
  --export_path="./datasets/wise_seg/exp/train_on_train_set/export/frozen_inference_graph-41.pb" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --num_classes=${3} \
  --crop_size=513 \
  --crop_size=513 \
  --inference_scales=1.0
```

The checkpoint gets exported successfully. Then I try to run inference using the sample notebook given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb). Specifically, when I run the following part, `0` gets printed in the output:

```
graph_path = './datasets/wise_seg/exp/train_on_train_set/export/frozen_inference_graph-41.pb'
MODEL = DeepLabModel(graph_path)
resized_im, seg_map = MODEL.run(Image.open('./datasets/wise_seg/WiSe/JPEGImages/130110-3MQQHISL3D-540_frame11610.jpg'))
print(sum(sum(seg_map)))
```

And the same happens for any given image. Why is this happening? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try training with more than 110 steps (2000+ at a minimum). Your loss should be lower than 1.9. Please also make sure that the labeled masks show pixel values of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 8. Also, setting num_classes = 9 is correct.